# Preencher Data Grid View com propriedade de objetos

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Tenho um formulário onde preciso preencher um `DataGridView` com os dados de uma lista de usuários. Para gerar esses dados, usei 3 classes:

Classe Usuário

```
namespace TesteDataGridView
{
    public class Usuario
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string login { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public Perfil perfil { get; set; }

        public Usuario()
        {
            //Cada usuario que eu crio obrigatoriamente já cria seu perfil
            perfil = new Perfil();
        }
    }
}
```

Classe Lista Usuario

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TesteDataGridView
{
    public class ListaUsuarios : List<Usuario>
    {
    }
}
```

Classe Perfil

```
namespace TesteDataGridView
{
    public class Perfil
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string descricao { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Arquivo do Formulário:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TesteDataGridView
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ListaUsuarios lstUsr; //Cria uma lista de usuários

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Instancia a lista de usuários
            lstUsr = new ListaUsuarios();

            //Não habilita a geração a
            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        }

        private void btnCriaListaUsuarios_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //cria alguns usuários e adiciona na lista
            Usuario u1 = new Usuario();
            u1.id = 1;
            u1.login = "usr1";
            u1.nome = "usuario1";
            u1.perfil.id = 3;
            u1.perfil.descricao = "operador";

            lstUsr.Add(u1);

            Usuario u2 = new Usuario();
            u2.id = 2;
            u2.login = "usr2";
            u2.nome = "usuario2";
            u2.perfil.id = 2;
            u2.perfil.descricao = "lider";

            lstUsr.Add(u2);

            Usuario u3 = new Usuario();
            u3.id = 3;
            u3.login = "usr3";
            u3.nome = "usuario3";
            u3.perfil.id = 1;
            u3.perfil.descricao = "administrador";

            lstUsr.Add(u3);
        }

        private void btnPreencheGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dgv.DataSource = null; //Limpa o grid;
            dgv.DataSource = lstUsr;
            dgv.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

No meu `DataGridView`, na propriedade `DataPropertyName`, eu configuro da seguinte forma o nome das colunas e o que deve ser apresentado nelas:

```
Column1 -  ID do Usuário     => DataPropertyName: id;
Column2 -  Nome do Usuário   => DataPropertyName: nome;
Column3 -  Login do Usuário  => DataPropertyName: login;
Column4 -  Perfil do Usuário => DataPropertyName: perfil.descricao;
```

Com as 3 primeiras colunas, tudo bem, mas a coluna de perfil, não é preenchida deixando o meu datagridview ficando assim:

[image]

Achei uma solução, onde falavam para fazer um override no método `toString` da classe Perfil e configurar o `DataPropertyName` da coluna 4 como "perfil", mas não achei muito legal, vejam:

```
namespace TesteDataGridView
{
    public class Perfil
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string descricao { get; set; }

        // Solução encontrada, fazer um override no método ToString()
        // Não achei muito legal...  :(

        public override string ToString()
        {
            //return base.ToString();
            return descricao.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O seu problema deve-se ao facto da DataGridView, quando está a popular as TextBox, invoca o método .ToString() dos objectos que a vão popular. Daí a solução que encontrou consiste em fazer override de .ToString() de forma a devolver o que pertende mostrar.

A solução ideal seria a DataGridView mostrar dados de duas datasources diferentes, o que no entanto não é possivel.

Assim, uma forma de resolver o seu problema seria, na altura de popular a DataGridView criar um novo tipo anonimo com recurso a LINQ e preencher a DataGridView com o tipo anónimo.

```
var newList = lstUsr.Select(usuario => new
{
    Id = usuario.id,
    Nome = usuario.login,
    LoginNome = usuario.login,
    PerfilDescricao = usuario.perfil.descricao
}).ToList();
```

Alterando o seu método:

```
    private void btnPreencheGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var novaListUsuario = lstUsr.Select(usuario => new
            {
                Id = usuario.id,
                Nome = usuario.login,
                LoginNome = usuario.login,
                PerfilDescricao = usuario.perfil.descricao
            }).ToList();


        dgv.DataSource = null; //Limpa o grid;
        dgv.DataSource = novaListUsuario;
        dgv.Refresh();
    }
```

Para esta alteração funcionar é necessario editar a DataGridView e mudar a DataSource para (none) no editor, assim como editar cada uma das colunas que pertende.

Ou seja, em cada uma das colunas, altere a DataPropertyName para coincidir com o nome da propriedade no tipo anónimo criado com que pertende popular a coluna.

([Pergunta similar no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407428/bind-multiple-lists-to-a-datagridview))

Comment: Perfeito Omni, funcionou exatamente como eu precisava.