# Preenchimento de Tabela com List

Tags: c#, winforms

Existe alguma função no Visual Studio em que seja possível preencher uma tabela com valores de um `List<>` sem um número determinado de posições?

Comment: Explique melhor sua pergunta. De que estamos falando? O que você já fez? O que é indeterminado?

Comment: O que entendes por uma *tabela*? Uma GridView? Uma ListView? Que framework usas?

Comment: eu tenho varios valores armazenados em `List<>`'s, e quero apresentar isso é um Windows Form, mas n quero colocar em um RichTextBox por exemplo pq fica tudo solto, dessa forma eu quero apresentar em uma tabela pra fique organizado, mas na tabela vem linhas e colunas pré-definidas, e eu n sei como fazer o visual ir criando linhas a medida que for avançando nas posições do `List`

Comment: Acredito que utilizando WPF em vez do WinForms fique bem mais fácil de fazer isto

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção de todos, mas eu consegui usando um datatable, adicionando os valores dos `List<>`s em colunas e depois adicionando ao datagridview, funcionou perfeitamente e ficou bem organizado

Answer (score 1):

O que você precisa fazer é utilizar o recurso LINQ para criar um novo tipo anônimo e, em seguida, preencher o DataGridView com o tipo anônimo que você criou.

```
List<Usuario> lstUsr = preencheLstUsr();
var newList = lstUsr.Select(usuario => new
{
    Id = usuario.id,
    Nome = usuario.login,
    LoginNome = usuario.login,
    PerfilDescricao = usuario.perfil.descricao
}).ToList();
```

O método ficaria assim:

```
private void btnPreencheGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Usuario> lstUsr = preencheLstUsr();
    var novaListUsuario = lstUsr.Select(usuario => new
        {
            Id = usuario.id,
            Nome = usuario.login,
            LoginNome = usuario.login,
            PerfilDescricao = usuario.perfil.descricao
        }).ToList();


    dgv.DataSource = null; //Limpa o grid;
    dgv.DataSource = novaListUsuario;
    dgv.Refresh();
}
```

> Para esta alteração funcionar é necessario editar a DataGridView e
>   mudar a DataSource para (none) no editor, assim como editar cada uma
>   das colunas que pertende.
>
> Ou seja, em cada uma das colunas, altere a DataPropertyName para
>   coincidir com o nome da propriedade no tipo anónimo criado com que
>   pertende popular a coluna.

Essa resposta é com base [nessa outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15671/26800), por isso usei como exemplo uma `List<Usuario>` com esses atributos `(Id,Nome,LoginNome,PerfilDescricao)`. Mas é só um exemplo que você pode adaptar para a sua realidade.

Comment: o que seria `lstUsr`?

Comment: alterado na resposta

Answer (score 0):

você pode atribuir uma List diretamente ao DataSource de uma GridView, porém sempre que você modificar a sua List terá que forçar uma atualização do GridView.

Então ao invés disto, aconselho o uso de uma BindingList.

```
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
BindingList<T> bindingList = new BindingList<T>(lista);
bindingSource.DataSource = bindingList;
gridView.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

Onde lista é a sua `List<T>`, `T` o tipo que a lista enumera e `gridView` o seu GridView.

Uma vez feito o Binding, você passa a manipular a `bindingList` ao invés da sua `lista`, caso queira monitorar qual quer mudança no `bindingList`pode implementar o evento `BindingList<T>.ListChanged`.